# Uncaught ReferenceError: sendcard is not defined

Tags: javascript, html

Ok so i keep getting this error but have no idea why... And yes i have checked other similar posts but nothing helped. Here is the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: sendcard is not defined
onclick @ kikcards.html:102
```

which is:

```
<tr><td colspan=2 align=center><img src="/Images/generate.png" width=150 onclick="sendcard()"></td></tr>
```

All the code i have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Kik Cards | Crazii</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/-default.css"/>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Permanent+Marker' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link id="kikicon" rel="kik-icon" href="kik.png"/>
    <script src="/navOpen.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.kik.com/kik/2.0.5/kik.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="body">

    <nav id="mainNav">
      <div id="logo">
        <a href="/index.html"><span>C</span>razii<span> </span> </a>
      </div>
      <div id="mobileToggle">
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
      </div>
      <ul id="mainMenu">
        <li>
          <a href="/index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/about.html">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">PS3 Modding</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/ebooks/ebooks.html">PDFs</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/kikcards.html">Kik Cards</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="mainContent">
        <div class="content">
            <article class="Content1">
                <header>
                    <h2><a href="#" title="1st Post"> Kik Cards</a></h2>
                </header>
                <footer>
                    <p class="post-info"> <br> </p>

                </footer>
                <content>
                    <p>
                        <table>
                            <tr><td style="text-align:right">Title:</td><td><input id="title"></td></tr>
                            <tr><td style="text-align:right">Text (optional):</td><td><input id="text"></td></tr>
                            <tr><td style="text-align:right">Main Title:</td><td><input id="maintitle"></td></tr>
                            <tr><td style="text-align:right">Little Icon (URL, optional):</td><td><input id="icon"></td></tr>
                            <tr><td style="text-align:right">Big Picture (URL, optional):</td><td><input id="pic">(If nothing is entered here, the default icon will be used)</td></tr>
                            <tr><td style="text-align:right">Redirect URL (optional):</td><td><input id="redirect"></td></tr>
                            <tr><td style="text-align:right">Big picture? (hides the title)</td><td><input type="checkbox" id="big"></td></tr> <!-- document.getElementById(big).checked -> bool -->
                            <tr><td style="text-align:right">Forward-able?</td><td><input type="checkbox" id="forward" checked=true></td></tr>
                            <tr><td colspan=2 align=center><img src="/Images/generate.png" width=150 onclick="sendcard()"></td></tr>
                        </table>
                    </p>
                </content>
            </article>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer class="mainFooter">
        <p> Copyright &copy; 2015 <a href="#" title="Crazii"><b>Crazii</b></p>
    </footer>

    <script>
    window.onload = function()
        {
            if (kik.message && kik.message['url']!="") {
                    window.location.replace(kik.message['url']);
                }
                var title = "";
                var maintitle = "";
                var body = "";
                var display = "";
                var bigpicture = "";
                var forwardable = "";
                var redirect = "";
                function precede(str, check_for) {
                    return str.slice(0, check_for.length) == check_for;
                }
                function sendcard() {
                    title = document.getElementById("title").value;

                    maintitle = document.getElementById("maintitle").value;
                    if (maintitle=="") {
                        maintitle = "Kik Cards | Crazii";
                    }

                    body = document.getElementById("text").value;

                    document.getElementById("kikicon").href = document.getElementById("icon").value;

                    display = document.getElementById("pic").value;
                    if (display == "") {
                        display = "http://crazii.herobo.com/Images/kik.png";
                    }
                    bigpicture = document.getElementById("big").checked;
                    if (document.getElementById("forward").checked == true) {
                        forwardable = false;
                    } else {
                        forwardable = true;
                    }

                    redirect = document.getElementById("redirect").value;
                    if (precede(redirect, "http://")) {
                        redirect = redirect;
                    } else if (precede(redirect, "https://")) {
                        redirect = redirect;
                    } else if (redirect == "") {
                        redirect = "http://crazii.herobo.com";
                    } else {
                        redirect = "http://"+redirect;
                    }
                    document.getElementById("webtitle").innerHTML = maintitle;

                    kik.send({
                    title: title,
                    text: body,
                    pic: display,
                    big: bigpicture,
                    noForward: forwardable,
                    data: {'url': redirect}
                });
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In advance i appreciate any help i can get, thanks!

Comment: Define your function sendcard() outside of window.load i.e (you can define it after <script>tag )

Comment: Yeahh i had it like that at first , put it in window.onload to fix another problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `sendcard()` is defined within the scope of the `window.onload` callback, as of that it is not visible in the global scope.

To self this you cab use `addEventListener`.

You need the be able to find your element, e.g. by adding an `id` to it:

```
<img src="/Images/generate.png" width=150 id="sendcard">
```

Then in your `window.onload`  you search for that element, and add an event listener:

```
document.getElementById("sendcard").addEventListener("click",sendcard, false);
```

You could also think of moving the `sendcard`  definition out of the callback, but then you would pollute the global scope which should be avoided.

Comment: Now i get an error on: document.getElementById("webtitle").innerHTML = maintitle; - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of nullsendcard @ kikcards.html:149

Comment: @xiCrazii in your code I don't see an element with the _id_ `webtitle` , so either you don't have such an element or it at least does not exists at the time you call `document.getElementById("webtitle")`. There is only an element with `id="title"` probably you are looking for this one.

Comment: Oh wow lmao, thanks for letting me know... I removed that and works fine now. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Kik Cards | Crazii</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/-default.css"/>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Permanent+Marker' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link id="kikicon" rel="kik-icon" href="kik.png"/>
    <script src="/navOpen.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.kik.com/kik/2.0.5/kik.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="body">

    <nav id="mainNav">
      <div id="logo">
        <a href="/index.html"><span>C</span>razii<span> </span> </a>
      </div>
      <div id="mobileToggle">
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
      </div>
      <ul id="mainMenu">
        <li>
          <a href="/index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/about.html">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">PS3 Modding</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/ebooks/ebooks.html">PDFs</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/kikcards.html">Kik Cards</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="mainContent">
        <div class="content">
            <article class="Content1">
                <header>
                    <h2><a href="#" title="1st Post"> Kik Cards</a></h2>
                </header>
                <footer>
                    <p class="post-info"> <br> </p>

                </footer>
                <content>
                    <p>
                        <table>
                            <tr><td style="text-align:right">Title:</td><td><input id="title"></td></tr>
                            <tr><td style="text-align:right">Text (optional):</td><td><input id="text"></td></tr>
                            <tr><td style="text-align:right">Main Title:</td><td><input id="maintitle"></td></tr>
                            <tr><td style="text-align:right">Little Icon (URL, optional):</td><td><input id="icon"></td></tr>
                            <tr><td style="text-align:right">Big Picture (URL, optional):</td><td><input id="pic">(If nothing is entered here, the default icon will be used)</td></tr>
                            <tr><td style="text-align:right">Redirect URL (optional):</td><td><input id="redirect"></td></tr>
                            <tr><td style="text-align:right">Big picture? (hides the title)</td><td><input type="checkbox" id="big"></td></tr> <!-- document.getElementById(big).checked -> bool -->
                            <tr><td style="text-align:right">Forward-able?</td><td><input type="checkbox" id="forward" checked=true></td></tr>
                            <tr><td colspan=2 align=center><img src="imgh.jpg" width=150 onclick="sendcard()" /></td></tr>
                        </table>
                    </p>
                </content>
            </article>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer class="mainFooter">
        <p> Copyright &copy; 2015 <a href="#" title="Crazii"><b>Crazii</b></p>
    </footer>

    <script>

            if (kik.message && kik.message['url']!="") {
                    window.location.replace(kik.message['url']);
                }
                var title = "";
                var maintitle = "";
                var body = "";
                var display = "";
                var bigpicture = "";
                var forwardable = "";
                var redirect = "";
                function precede(str, check_for) {
                    return str.slice(0, check_for.length) == check_for;
                }
                function sendcard() {
                alert("sdf");
                    title = document.getElementById("title").value;

                    maintitle = document.getElementById("maintitle").value;
                    if (maintitle=="") {
                        maintitle = "Kik Cards | Crazii";
                    }

                    body = document.getElementById("text").value;

                    document.getElementById("kikicon").href = document.getElementById("icon").value;

                    display = document.getElementById("pic").value;
                    if (display == "") {
                        display = "http://crazii.herobo.com/Images/kik.png";
                    }
                    bigpicture = document.getElementById("big").checked;
                    if (document.getElementById("forward").checked == true) {
                        forwardable = false;
                    } else {
                        forwardable = true;
                    }

                    redirect = document.getElementById("redirect").value;
                    if (precede(redirect, "http://")) {
                        redirect = redirect;
                    } else if (precede(redirect, "https://")) {
                        redirect = redirect;
                    } else if (redirect == "") {
                        redirect = "http://crazii.herobo.com";
                    } else {
                        redirect = "http://"+redirect;
                    }
                    document.getElementById("webtitle").innerHTML = maintitle;

                    kik.send({
                    title: title,
                    text: body,
                    pic: display,
                    big: bigpicture,
                    noForward: forwardable,
                    data: {'url': redirect}
                });
            }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Remove :-   `window.onload = function()`
        {
and end image tag

Comment: While this would work, you should avoid it., because it will pollute the global scope with a bunch of variables and functions. Which might conflict with other scripts in future.